Не получается расположить кнопки в CustomTkinter
захотел написать код на CustomTkinter, но столкнулся с проблемой, что при расположении кнопки, кнопка не двигается по X на убывание, а если двигать по прибыванию, то двигается кнопка с самим Label. Вот сам код:
import customtkinter as ctk

ctk.set_appearance_mode("light")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("blue")

class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("400x400")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        
        self.text = ctk.CTkLabel(
            self,
            text="Отрезать руку?",
            width=30,
            height=20,
            font=("Arial", 20)
        )
        self.text.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=130, pady=5)
        
        self.close_button = ctk.CTkButton(
            self,
            text="Нет!",
            width=70,
            height=50,
            font=("Arial", 19)
        )
        self.close_button.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=40, pady=140)
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

